# How can I add a string to a request using rewrite rules?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm developing a bi-lingual site & am trying to come up with a simple method of heving multilingual images, how can I add a string to a request using rewrite rules? For example:

If the user requests: http://mysite.com/assets/img/myimage.jpg - that's the image I want served, however if the user requests: http://mysite.com/FR/assets/img/myimage.jpg, I actually want to serve: http://mysite.com/assets/img/myimage_FR.jpg

Is this possible?

Comment: You should probably not even use mod_rewrite for that, but Content Negotiation instead: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html

Comment: hmm, looks good - but from reading the docs, it looks as though the relies on the browser to supply lang preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a [pretty simple](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite) match (i.e. `mod_rewrite` isn't actually needed):

```
RedirectMatch ^/([^/]+)/assets/img/(.+)\.jpg /assets/img/$2_$1.jpg
```

Note that this only works on JPEGs - it's assuming the requests come in for `.jpg` files. Also, if the "translated" image isn't there, you'll get a 404; with some more work you could make it smarter to only redirect if the translated file exists.